# Changing right margin modifies position of title. Bug or feature?

Tags: beamer

I am trying to understand why modifying the right margin should change the position of a box of width equal to the paperwidth.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\setbeamersize{text margin right=0cm}
% Modifying the right margin makes the beamercolorbox move to the right althought the box still
% is of width paperwidth.
% The LINEND is moving as expected.

\setbeamercolor{bgcolor}{fg=black,bg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{bgcolor}Box\end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
LINESTART \hfill LINEEND
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us *how* you modify the right-hand margin.

Comment: By uncommenting the second line in above example.

Answer (score 2):

`\setbeamersize{text margin right=0cm}` works as expected, but `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth] ...` automatically makes its contents centered. This is clearer when you change the `...` part of `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{...}` to, for example

- `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax] ...` or
- `\leavevmode\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax}{1pt}`.

From the user guide for `beamer` v3.59, sec. 12.5, documentation of key `wd` of `beamercolorbox`,

> If the width is larger than the normal text width, as specified by the value of `\textwidth`, the width of the resulting box is reset to the width `\textwidth`, but intelligent negative skips are inserted at the left and right end of the box.

In your example, `\paperwidth = <text margin left> + \textwidth + <text margin right>`, in which `<text margin left> = 1cm` and `<text margin right>` is set to `0pt`. Therefore `\paperwidth > \textwidth`.

Comment: I played around with the example and the content **of** beamercolorbox always is rendered left-bound with respect to the colored background of beamercolorbox. It *never* is centered. Do you mean that the beamercolorbox itself is centered? If yes, with respect to *what* is the beamercolorbox centered? I fail to understand the concept of "centered" when it is not clear with regard to *what*. Can I turn off these "intelligent skips"? How? I want the box to do what I ask without "intelligence" of its own :-)

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog "Do you mean that the beamercolorbox itself is centered?" Yes. You can think that `\hspace{-x}{beamercolorbox}\hspace{-x}` is inserted, where `x = .5(\paperwidth-\textwidth)`. I've added a workaround to my answer.

Comment: @muzhimuzhi-z What do you mean with "yes"? An object cannot be centered as such. It only can be centered WITH REGARD TO something else. That is why I added "IF YES, with respect to what is the beamercolorobox centered?" The page? The newly set left and right margin? The original old margins? All of this leads to different positions! I am sorry but I really do not understand the concept of "centered" without a reference frame. It simply is not defined without a reference frame.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog Perhaps I used a bad word, and let's directly learn from the doc. Suppose you have `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=<dimen>] contents\end{beamercolorbox}`. Case 1: `<dimen> <= \textwidth`, then the width of colorbox is `<dimen>`. Case 2: `<dimen> > \textwidth`, then the width of colorbox is always `\textwidth`. The final output is something like `\hskip\x\hbox to <dimen>{<contents of beamercolorbox>}\hskip\x`, where `\x = .5(\textwidth-<dimen>)`.

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog In saying "centered", wrap the whole `\hskip\x\hbox to <dimen>{...}\hskip\x` in another `\hbox`, then the inner `\hbox` is centered with regard to the outer `\hbox`.

Comment: Thanx for your help. With regard to centering: I then still do not know the position of the content on the page as the question is just shifted to the next box level and I then have to know that box position. But I did find a solution now which is working for my use cases. I shall post it here, as soon as I have distilled it down to a minimal variant.

Answer (score -1):

I have the following solution to my problem. For some reason I still do not completely understand, beamercolorbox behaves differently than my understanding of the manual. However, experimenting with a few cases led me to a correction of the position, which can be made after changing the beamer size. Placing these corrections into my own beamerFix package is my current solution for slide generation. May the idea be helpful for others coming here - and maybe a better fix will be found.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerFix@deltaMargin
\setlength\beamerFix@deltaMargin{\dimexpr 0.5\beamer@leftmargin - 0.5\beamer@rightmargin}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.4cm, text margin right=0.4cm}

\addtolength\beamerFix@deltaMargin{\dimexpr 0.5\beamer@rightmargin - 0.5\beamer@leftmargin}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{bgcolor}{fg=black,bg=red}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip\ifdim\beamerFix@deltaMargin>0cm{}\else{\hspace*{\beamerFix@deltaMargin}}\fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{bgcolor}Box \hfill \insertframetitle \hfill End\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

Start \hfill End

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```